# How can I join two tables on multiple columns in CakePHP 3?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm using CakePHP v3

I have a table that looks like this:

Document:

```
id | section | paragraph
-------------------------
1       2         4
```

Text:

```
id | section | paragraph | theText
---------------------------------------
12      2         4        Blah blah
```

So in SQL I could do something like this;

```
SELECT * FROM document 
INNER JOIN text 
ON document.section=text.section 
AND document.paragraph=text.paragraph
```

How can I do something like this in CakePHP using the ORM?  The Primary key in both tables is set up to be the id column.

I've looked into `foreignKey` and `binidingKey` in Cake's docs, but I can't see how to use multiple columns in those.

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html.

FWIW, here is a sample of code that shows how I want to access them.

```
$cond = [
        'contain' => ['text']
      ];

$docs = $this->Documents->find('all',$cond);
```

Comment: Take a look at the "condition" option for how you set up the models

Comment: @RobbieAverill you mean when I'm trying to access them?  So the issue is that unless they properly join, they table size inflates to an unwieldly size.  As far as I understand, conditions are simply WHERE commands which are executed after it JOINs.  Either way I'll update the question to include that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Just use arrays to express the columns that should be matched:

```
$this->belongsTo('Things', [
    'bindingKey' => ['key1', 'ke2'],
    'foreignKey' => ['fk1', 'fk2']
]);
```

That will match `key1 = fk1` and `key2 = fk2`