# CakePHP 3 belongsTo over multiple columns with default values

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have two tables with customer data.  I need a join on two columns (primaryKey und customer_id). The problem and a solution are described here: 
[How can I join two tables on multiple columns in CakePHP 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32341773/how-can-i-join-two-tables-on-multiple-columns-in-cakephp-3)

There are also some few tables that contain both customer and "global" data.  The global data applies to all customers and can be recognized by the customer_id "0".

The result should look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
  table1 
INNER JOIN 
  table2 
ON (table1.table2_id = table2.id AND 
    (table1.customer_id=table2.customer_id OR table2.customer_id=0)) 
WHERE 1;
```

Is it possible (and if so, how) to do this with CakePHP relations?

> UPDATE: It does not seem to work yet

```
$this->belongsTo('Calibrations', [
    'foreignKey' => 'calibration_id',
    'joinType' => 'INNER',
    'conditions' => [
        'Foods.calibration_id = Calibrations.id', 
        'OR' => [
            'Foods.tenant_id' => 'Calibrations.tenant_id',
            'Calibrations.tenant_id' => '0'
        ]
    ]
]);
```

results in

```
...
INNER JOIN calibrations Calibrations ON (
  Foods.calibration_id = Calibrations.id 
AND (
  Foods.tenant_id = 'Calibrations.tenant_id' 
  OR Calibrations.tenant_id = 0
) 
  AND Calibrations.id = (Foods.calibration_id)
) 
...
```

> 2nd UPDATE:

sorry for my hasty inquiry, i've found the solution:

```
$this->belongsTo('Calibrations', [
    'foreignKey' => 'calibration_id',
    'joinType' => 'INNER',
    'conditions' => [
        'OR' => [
            'Foods.tenant_id = Calibrations.tenant_id',
            'Calibrations.tenant_id' => '0'
        ]
    ]
]);
```

results in

```
INNER JOIN calibrations Calibrations ON (
(
  Foods.tenant_id = Calibrations.tenant_id 
  OR Calibrations.tenant_id = 0
) 
  AND Calibrations.id = (Foods.calibration_id)
)
```

Thats the solution...

Comment: In english, please.

Comment: thanks the translation is fine

Answer (score 0):

Join conditions can also be expressed as an array of conditions:

```
$query = $this->Table1->find()
    ->hydrate(false)
    ->join([
        't2' => [
            'table' => 'table2',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'conditions' => [
                'Table1.table2_id = t2.id',
                'OR' => [
                    [
                       'Table1.customer_id' => 't2.customer_id',
                       't2.customer_id' => '0'
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]);
```

See also [Adding Joins](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#adding-joins)

> UPDATE:

The same could be done with `contain()`:

```
    // Table1
    $this->belongsTo('Table2', [
        'className' => 'Table2',
        'foreignKey' => 'table2_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER',
        'conditions' => [
                'Table1.table2_id = Table2.id',
                'OR' => [
                    [
                       'Table1.customer_id' => 'Table2.customer_id',
                       'Table2.customer_id' => '0'
                    ]
                ]
            ]
    ]);

    // Controller
    $query = $this->Table1->find()
        ->contain('Table2');
```

See also

- [Eager Loading Associations Via Contain](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#eager-loading-associations-via-contain)
- [BelongsTo Associations](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#belongsto-associations)

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I think that would be a "workaround" solution. I'd rather have it if it were automatic / configured, Then I could outsource it to a Behavior. The background is supposed to be a SaaS solution and I do not want the developer to worry about it. The model should do this by itself ...

Comment: This looks like the right solution. I'll test it tomorrow. Thank you very much for your quick reply...

Comment: I've tested it, but does not seem to work yet. Can you please look at my update again...